# h5ai use on a CDN?

Tags: cdn, dreamhost

Is it possible to use the h5ai "pretty" index UI on a CDN? I'm using Dreamhosts' DreamObjects and have it installed correctly (I've used it before on standard hosting sites). Am only getting an XML parse of the data back.

See it here: https://randassets.objects.cdn.dream.io/

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you would like to see is a pretty-looking list of files and directories on a web page, like a file browser to explore the content of your DreamObjects bucket. If that's the case, hi5ai would not work because from what I understand, hi5ai doesn't natively speak neither the S3 API nor the OpenStack Swift ones. hi5ai relies on a web server and a php interpreter, which are not provided by DreamObjects.
Maybe if you expand on your use case I can suggest you other tools you could use to browse your collection of files, something like [ownCloud](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/OwnCloud) (and more specifically [how to configure DreamObjects with ownCloud](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/How_to_Use_ownCloud_with_DreamObjects)) or others.

Comment: Thank you for the info, you're exactly right. I have been exploring various ways to store and serve assets and wanted to see if h5ai was able to "prettify" a directory listing.